# Enable Caching in Spring Data Redis

Tags: java, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I was trying to implement Spring data redis and was trying to enable cache. But I think I am doing something wrong. I even have tried reading the docs and following but still couldn't make that work. I am pretty novice to spring data redis. I am using 1.5.1-RELEASE with jedis 2.6.2. This is my function for adding the words:

```
public Long addWordWithItsMeaningToDictionary (String word,
                                                   String meaning) {
        Long index = redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush(word, meaning);
        return index;
    }
```

And this one is for retrieving:

```
@Cacheable("words")
    public List<String> getAllTheMeaningsForAWord (String word) {
        List<String> meanings = redisTemplate.opsForList().range(word, 0, -1);
        System.out.println (word);
        return meanings;
    }
```

This is my understanding about the impelementation, first cache will be hit, if result is found, fetch that, otherwise, bring the word from redis and store that in cache. This is the exception stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: WRONGTYPE
>   Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value; nested
>   exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException:
>   WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.get(JedisConnection.java:1102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.get(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$1.doInRedis(RedisCache.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$1.doInRedis(RedisCache.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$AbstractRedisCacheCallback.doInRedis(RedisCache.java:367)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:279)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:201)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:181)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
>     at
>   com.ssc.dictionary.dao.DictionaryDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e9ccfb0.getAllTheMeaningsForAWord()
>     at com.ssc.dictionary.config.Main.dictionary(Main.java:36)  at
>   com.ssc.dictionary.config.Main.main(Main.java:26) Caused by:
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: WRONGTYPE Operation
>   against a key holding the wrong kind of value     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:113)  at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:138)   at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:192)  at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:282)
>     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryBulkReply(Connection.java:201)
>     at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.get(BinaryJedis.java:127)    at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.get(JedisConnection.java:1100)

Can anyone tell, what I am doing wrong? Or if I need to enable cache before putting records in redis too?

Comment: you are trying to cache the result of redis ..which is generally used for caching...!!?? and if so how are you caching the "redis-cache" result.
Also make sure that you are not caching same key with but diff data type,cause your exception points to that. eg
`@cacheable
public String getAntonym(String word){.......}`

   P.S checkout this [http://blog.joshuawhite.com/java/caching-with-spring-data-redis] and make sure if this is not what you want

Comment: Did you figure it out...?

Comment: the error indicates that you are inserting an unexpected type of value.  Could join "redisTemplate" bean configuration?